# How to generate ready-for-web-server source?

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm trying to find a way to generate (with generate.py source-all) application code that is ready for running from web server (eg. Tomcat).
The only thing that prevents me from doing this is the fact that myapp.js contains filesystem URIs in libinfo object:

```
var libinfo = {
  "__out__":{"sourceUri":"script"},
  "myapp":{"resourceUri":"../source/resource","sourceUri":"../source/class"},
  "qx":{
    "resourceUri":"file:///C:/dev/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk/framework/source/resource",
    "sourceUri":"file:///C:/dev/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk/framework/source/class",
    "sourceViewUri":"https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/%{qxGitBranch}/framework/source/class/%{classFilePath}#L%{lineNumber}"
  }
};
```

When I manually change resourceUri & sourceUri from

```
file:///C:/dev/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk/framework/source/...
```

to

```
/myapp/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk/framework/source/...
```

application page successfully loads in the browser with all the dependencies (generated sources are already in document root, and "qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk" framework content loads due to the mapping /myapp/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk => C:\Dev\qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk set up on the server).

Is there a way to tell generate.py that my SDK framework files should be accessed through an URL (/myapp/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk/...) instead of filesystem URI?

(I can see there are a number of "compile-options" that can be specified in config.json (qooxdoo Documentation Release 5.1: chapter 11.3.3 - Generator Config Keys), but looks like none of them solves the problem)

Answer (score 0):

In your config.json you will have a "jobs" section containing a "libraries" section, containing a "library" array - your application is a library, as is Qooxdoo, as is any contribs so it will look something like this:

```
"jobs" : {
    "libraries" : {
        "=library" : [ {
            "manifest" : "${QOOXDOO_PATH}/framework/Manifest.json"
        }, {
            "manifest" : "Manifest.json"
        }
    },
```

Each "library" object can have a "uri" property, so for your example you probably want something like this:

```
"jobs" : {
    "libraries" : {
        "=library" : [ {
            "manifest" : "${QOOXDOO_PATH}/framework/Manifest.json",
            "uri" : "/some/other/uri/qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk"
        }, {
            "manifest" : "Manifest.json"
        }
    },
```

and then on your web server, either position the qooxdoo-5.0.1-sdk directory appropriately or create a mapping to it.

Comment: Sorry, I left off experimenting with qooxdoo so I can't verify your answer. Thanks, though.